# how do i prevent root-site deployment in bamboo from failing when IIS is already stopped

Tags: deployment, bamboo

I am deploying root-site deployments and it keeps failing whenever it seems that IIS is stopped. Below is the error i am getting from the failed log in bamboo.

```
VERBOSE: Performing action iisreset /Stop on web4.testweb.******.com
    C:\bambooscripts\ClusterAwareDeploy-RootSiteAndComDependencies.v2.ps1 : Aborting due to an error!
    At D:\AtlassianData\bamboo-agent2-home\temp\4489217-4554753-124649565-ScriptBuildTask-17453259024217579627.ps1:23 char:6
    + "@ | c:\bambooscripts\ClusterAwareDeploy-RootSiteAndComDependencies.v ...
    +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,ClusterAwareDeploy-RootSiteAndComDependencies.v2.ps1
    
    
    ErrorDetails          :
    Exception             : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: The Windows Process Activation Service service is not started.
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
    PipelineIterationInfo : {}
    ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
    TargetObject          : The Windows Process Activation Service service is not started.
    Category              : NotSpecified
    Activity              :
    Reason                : RemoteException
    TargetName            : The Windows Process Activation Service service is not started.
    TargetType            : String
    
    The Windows Process Activation Service service is not started.
    At C:\bambooscripts\IISFunctions.ps1:319 char:22
    + ...    'Stop' { $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostName -ErrorAc ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The Windows Pro...is not started.:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
        + PSComputerName        : p********db.******.lan
    
    Failing task since return code of [powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command D:\AtlassianData\bamboo-agent2-home\temp\4489217-4554753-124649565-ScriptBuildTask-17453259024217579627.ps1] was 1 while expected 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am deploying a root-site with Bamboo CI and it keeps failing because bamboo detects IIS Is Stopped.MY questions is how can i prevent bamboo from failing my root-site deployment when IIS is already stopped.